# Response.Redirect loading is not finish

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please be assume that I have already login.
I have two pages. PickupList.aspx. There has a button named as "New".
When I click New button page url changed as PickupJobForm.aspx?mode=new
But loading time is not finish and form not appear.

After logout the application. And I copy and paste this url PickupJobForm.aspx?mode=new. And I press enter key from keyboard. Login form appears. After I logIn ready, I can see the create job web form.

What is the differences?

One more info is that our client computer is window 10. And we are using the Trend Micro Apex One.

`protected void rbtnNew_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Response.Redirect("~/PickupJobForm.aspx?mode=new", false);
 }`

Comment: Can you show the relevant code in question please

Comment: can you confirm the path to redirect page is same at both place (means from login and button click) it should be ~/PickupJobForm.aspx?mode=new

Comment: Yes the same. From the pickup job form is redirect the like by using the Response.Redirect("~/PickupJobForm.aspx?mode=new", false); **url redirect links** Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fPickupJobForm.aspx%3fmode%3dnew&mode=new

Comment: @ShowboyLay both URL not seen same it means Login.aspx and PickupJobForm.aspx are on the same path or say in the same folder but when you redirect from PickupList.aspx it search PickupJobForm.aspx in the root folder, please confirm all these are in the same folder or same path.

Comment: PickupJobForm.aspx and PickupList.aspx are the same folder. But Login.aspx is in the root folder.